# Can't find publish_date with newspaper3k

Tags: python, python-newspaper, newspaper3k

I want to scrape an article from a website with the newspaper library (newspaper3k). However, it doesn't find the published_date for the article, which is div.source-date in the website's source text, and the authors (or source rather), which is div.delfi-source-name in the website's source text. How can I scrape the date and the author/source?

Website/URL example: https://www.delfi.lt/en/politics/foreign-ministry-tsikhanouskayas-consultation-needed-for-treating-belarusians-in-lithuania.d?id=91531501

My code:

```
import newspaper
from newspaper import Article
from newspaper import Source
import pandas as pd

article = Article("url")
article.download()
article.parse()
article.nlp()

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Title':article.title, 'Author':article.authors, 'Text':article.text,
                    'published_date':article.publish_date, 'Source':article.source_url}])

df.to_excel('Delfi-1.xlsx')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date element in your source is located in 2 locations.  The one that you see `Wednesday, October 19, 2022` is located in a `div` tag that `newspaper3k` cannot parse without using `BeautifulSoup`.

The second date is hidden in the meta tags, which `newspaper3k` can parse with some additional code.

```
from newspaper import Config
from newspaper import Article
from newspaper.article import ArticleException

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'

config = Config()
config.browser_user_agent = USER_AGENT
config.request_timeout = 10

base_url = 'https://www.delfi.lt/en/politics/foreign-ministry-tsikhanouskayas-consultation-needed-for-treating-belarusians-in-lithuania.d?id=91531501'
try:
    article = Article(base_url, config=config)
    article.download()
    article.parse()
    article_meta_data = article.meta_data

    article_title = [value['title'] for (key, value) in article_meta_data.items() if key == 'og']
    print(article_title)

    article_published_date = [value['recs']['publishtime'] for key, value in article_meta_data.items()
                              if key == 'cXenseParse']
    print(article_published_date)

    article_description = [value['description'] for (key, value) in article_meta_data.items() if key == 'og']
    print(article_description)

except ArticleException as error:
    print(error)
```

Output

```
["Foreign Ministry: Tsikhanouskaya's consultation needed for treating Belarusians in Lithuania"]
['2022-10-19T11:38:07+0300']
["As Belorus, a Belarus-owned sanatorium in Lithuania's southern resort of Druskininkai, complaints over the fact that Lithuania fails to issue visas to Belarusian citizens, forcing the sanatorium to fire a quarter of its staff, Lithuania's Foreign Ministry suggests coordinating the list of arrivals with Belarusian opposition leaders Sviatlana Tsikhanouskaya's office in Vilnius."]
```

P.S. Newspaper3k has multiple ways to extract the publish dates from articles. Take a look at this [document](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview) that I wrote on how to use Newspaper3k.